# Sonarqube and Cucumber features

Tags: sonarqube, cucumber

Is there any way to include the test coverage of Cucumber features and other useful statistics in the SonarQube analysis? I have done a bit of researching, but couldn't find a proper plugin.

Comment: SonarQube can read many kinds of test coverage reports. What tool do you use to compute test coverage?

Comment: All the projects use Cobertura.

Comment: What is the language of the code you cover with your Cucumber features? Java? If so, see http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project

Comment: The code is written in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/PwbASuTpNJU) (written after the OP's question), David Racadon added:

> As far as I understand:
>
> - It is not possible to run an analysis on a project containing only test code because the '`sonar.sources`' property is mandatory.
>
>   - Measures on test code are not aggregated at project level.
>       As far as I am concerned, I consider test files part of the project the same way source files are. Thus, measures of test files should be aggregated on top of source files.
>       For now, SonarQube shows that your project is 1,000 lines even if you have 0 or 10,000 lines of test code on top of those 1,000 lines of source code. For me, SonarQube gives you a biased estimate of the size of your project and the effort of maintenance.

The closest would then be his plugin [`racodond/sonar-gherkin-plugin`](https://github.com/racodond/sonar-gherkin-plugin) which:

- analyzes [Cucumber Gherkin feature files](https://docs.cucumber.io/gherkin/reference/) and:
- Computes metrics: lines of code, number of scenarios, etc.
- Checks various guidelines to find out potential bugs and code smells through more than 40 checks
- Provides the ability to write your own checks